# How to save this query to controller and model to my database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How to save this query to my database? The query have 10 text boxes in a row but I can't save it to the database.  Maybe my controller is wrong.

Here's my create.blade.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

             $(document).ready(function(){
            var x =0;  
             $(".add-row").click(function(){
             x++;
                $("table > tbody").append('<input class="form-control" type="text" name="MFI" placeholder="Major Final Output" id="MFI" value="Participate in school activities">'); 

                }); //add input box


           }); 

              $(document).on('click', '.delete-row', function(){
                  alert("ROWS DELETED! ")
                  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

My notescontroller.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $inputData= $request->all();

    Note::create($inputData);

    $ipcrId=$request->ipcr_id;

    return redirect()->route('ipcr.show', compact('ipcrId')); 

}
```

My note.php (Model)

```
protected $fillable=['MFI','successIndicator','actualaccomplishments','distribution','Q1','E2','T3','   A4','Ave','Remarks','ipcr_id'];

public function ipcr()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ipcr::class);
}
```

Comment: i have a query that each click of the button produce 10boxes in a row . i want to save it in my database also it have same id so that it will be one to many relationship . i want to save it in a way that query can save 10boxes in a row and many columns in one id . my regards thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that for multiple rows you need to name the input as an array:

```
<input type="text" name="mfi[]">
```

Then in your controller you can do:

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $ipcr = Ipcr::find($request->ipcr_id);

    foreach ($request->mfi as $key => $value) {

        $ipcr->notes()->create([

            'mfi' => $request->mfi[$key]
            // repeat for other fields

        ]);

    }

    return redirect()->route('ipcr.show', compact('ipcrId'));

}
```

(as long as you have the inverse relationship in your Ipcr model):

```
public function notes() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Note::class);
}
```

There will be much cleaner ways of getting this done but I think this should work. I recommend copious use of `dd($request)` in the controller until you understand your form data in the $request, and you likely need some **validation** in there too. Good luck.

Comment: hello sir, theres an error . how to configure this? 

FatalErrorException in NotesController.php line 54:
Call to a member function ipcr() on null